# Play 2: How to compare strings in scala template?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a form object and I need to check if the value of a field is equal a certain string

I'm trying this but it is not working

```
 @if(sp.pageType.equals("customreCare")) {
   //render this specific div 
  } else {
   //render this other div
  }
```

but unfortunately it is not working, what is the syntax for that?

Comment: you can compare two strings with ==

Comment: maybe it doesn't work because of the typo? no wait...typos

Comment: didn't have the typo in the code, corrected the post

Comment: with == i get '(' expected but ')' found. error message on the page!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `==` operator for comparing strings:

```
@defining("something") {whatToTest =>
    @if(whatToTest == "something"){ There is something } else { There is.... nothing }
}
```

so in your case (of course make sure that there are no typos in the conditions like `customreCare` ...):

```
@if(sp.pageType == "customreCare") {
     //render this specific div 
} else {
     //render this other div
}
```

Comment: kind of annoying I had @if (sp.page....) instead of @if(...
(the space between if and the ( is important apparently!